# "Four dozen" or "Four dozens"

Tags: quantifiers, quantificational-nouns

Out of the three, which is the best option and with which grammatical rule:

> 1. I have four dozens of mango.
> 2. I have four dozen of mangoes.
> 3. I have four dozens of mangoes.

Comment: please read the answer again, I have made some changes, I guess.

Comment: Uh, none of the above: you either have "dozens of mangoes" (no number), or "four dozen mangoes" (no "of"). None of the versions with both a number and an "of" sound natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Hundred, thousand, pair, dozen,*** and ***couple*** take the same form both in the singular and in the plural only when they are used after numerals or after **several** or **a few.**

> *Three hundred (not hundreds), two pair, three couple, five dozen etc.*

Example:

> - He gave me a sum of three hundred rupees.
> - He bought two pair of shoes.
> - There are five dozen mangoes in the basket.

**NOTE:** In modern English, "pairs" and "couples" are more usual.

Example:

> - He bought two pairs of shoes.
> - Five couples were present at the meeting.

When the nouns of numbers are followed immediately by "of," their plural forms are used.

Example:

> - Hundreds of people.
> - Hundreds of thousands of people.

Based on that, the correct answer is #2:

> - I have four dozen mangoes. **or** I have four dozen of mangoes.
> - I have two pair of dresses.

***But,*** we say:

> - I have dozens of mangoes.
> - I have a number of pairs of dresses.

---

**EDIT**

Since many are concluding that using "of" is not correct, It is uncommon, but it is not wrong either, maybe to American/British, but It is very common to use "of" after "dozen" in India. Since the OP is Indian, I have provided a source from an Indian book.

[image]

But as you can see here, the results are very contrasting to the previous one:

[image]

Here is something that may help you: 
[English Grammar without Tears](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=aStaYLte1uMC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%22He+gave+me+a+sum+of+three+hundred+rupees%22&source=bl&ots=dRIA6-akGr&sig=ydxLDxNDsNz50A6k33R6AAi8xZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI0qvj-83RyAIVgRqOCh2NDgjv#v=onepage&q=%22He%20gave%20me%20a%20sum%20of%20three%20hundred%20rupees%22&f=false)

Comment: Based on your answer it should be dozens of mangoes.  Since dozen is being followed by of.

Comment: @SeemaBhukar If you remove the number "four," then you can say "dozens of mangoes"

Comment: @SeemaBhukar I hope your query is solved now.

Comment: A lot of this sounds weird or simply wrong to my American ear. If I had 48 mangoes, I'd say 4 dozen mangoes, no of. Also, I'd always treat a pair as an entity, and say two pairs of shoes, never two pair. Skimming through the book you linked to, a lot of the examples aren't quite normal in American English.

Comment: As a UK native speaker, I agree with Karen. A British person would say four dozen mangos.

Comment: The only reasonable usage of "four dozens of X" in British English would be if the items X were packaged in groups of 12, and this is a shorthand for "four packages, each containing one dozen Xs". That was certainly used in old business accounts, etc, e.g. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=W3VjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR15&lpg=PR15&dq=%22four+dozens+of%22&source=bl&ots=BPzF1cApUG&sig=0DKndrjRZyz6L0WdcA0ixvR5IGE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBmoVChMI5o3dl6XSyAIVAQsaCh07SAlI#v=onepage&q=%22four%20dozens%20of%22&f=false.

Comment: ... and apparently it is still used in Indian English, e.g. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GLdZWpvqUV8C&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=%22four+dozens+of%22&source=bl&ots=yHSMgfHnCk&sig=puQjr2CbYnTZRYfZQ9B9G14vkYw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBGoVChMI5o3dl6XSyAIVAQsaCh07SAlI#v=onepage&q=%22four%20dozens%20of%22&f=false

Comment: @Karen The OP is Indian. This might be weird to American or British ear, but I have seen and heard "[X] dozen of [Y]" which I guess very acceptable to Indians. Another link, [Point 8-A,B](http://www.affairscloud.com/best-spotting-error-rules-with-examples-part-1/)

Comment: @Usernew Buy maybe we shouldn't be promoting pidgin as correct on ell?

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that what you have is 48 mangoes; you have four dozen mangoes.

The reason for this is that "four dozen" is a number. You wouldn't say "I have four of mango", "fours of mangoes" etc.

Use of dozen is, of course, an English oddity, but it does compare to the other units OK: So "I have four hundred mangoes" is the same construction.

Comment: why you said “What we have is 48mangoes” and not “What we have are 48mangoes”

Answer (score 15):

The rule is simple. It depends on whether you're using `dozen' as an adjective or as a noun. Nouns can be singular or plural; adjectives are unit-less (as the noun that the adjective is qualifying carries the numerical dimension).
So, the following are correct:

### Dozen as a Noun

> Dozens of mangoes were destroyed (*what a pity!*).
>
> Give me a dozen ['of those' implied].

### Dozen as an Adjective

> Four dozen mangoes were not destroyed (*thank God!)*
>
> I have a few dozen shoes.

Similarly, we never say 'five thousands dollars', as we're using it as an adj.

Additionally, I'd like to point that 'pair' is not an adjective, but a noun.

Comment: Best answer because it includes a simple, solid rule.

Comment: I think i'd prefer "adjectives are not inflected for number" rather than "adjectives are unit-less," because a *metre* is a unit, and the phrase *two-metre plank* contains an adjective with a unit. (I know what's meant; I agree with the analysis; I don't think this "unit-less" description is the right way of expressing it.)

Comment: I think this answer is putting the cart before the horse. Depending on how you use the word in the sentence, it changes whether you the word is an adjective or a noun. If someone is asking how to use it in the sentence, they aren't going to know whether they are using it as a noun or an adjective.

Comment: @Shane, the answer is directed towards the question primarily about *choosing the words*. If my understanding is correct, the burden is on the speaker to make the word a noun or adjective (or verb); which in turn depends on the subject, object and context of the statement. Another way of saying that is, we don't end up with a sentence, we have to design it.

Comment: @shahzebkohari If the question was "I need an adjective in this sentence, is '4 dozen of mango' an adjective, or, is '4 dozens of mangoes' an adjective?" then saying Option A is a noun, Option B is an adjective would be a useful answer. But to assume someone who doesn't know what word to use knows whether they want an adjective or a noun in their sentence is a bit of a stretch. This answer seems like "Oh, you don't understand high school physics? Maybe if I explain some advanced theoretical Quantum ElectroDynamics to you it will clear things up."

Comment: @Shane Sorry to interrupt you. I actually didn't find the answer misleading. Or making things harder for OP. this one simply says that particular word has two parts-of-speech, and then demonstrate their use for every parts-of-speech. What's wrong with that? I am not a language student, nor did I ever studied it formally. You might be more more qualified than me in matters related to language, but my experience is that when language is involved there is often no straight forward answer. Hmm may be because we are not dealing with computer languages and all :-)

Comment: @Man_From_India The only thing wrong with it is that it doesn't answer the question. When someone asks which "Out of these two, which one is correct in this case?", telling them that depending on the situation both can be correct doesn't tell them which one *is* correct.

Comment: @Shane I do agree but not completely. "if it sounds correct" has either "yes" or "no" as an answer. That doesn't help the OP much. Does it? And for that a comment is enough. But yes it's true that the answerer should have included some lines stating which of the sentences the OP quoted sounds correct. (thinking about it, I myself haven't included it directly :P)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTES FROM OED -**

> A group or set of twelve. Originally as a noun, followed by *of*, but often with the ellipsis of *of*, and thus in singular = twelve. 
>   Also, used colloq. in plural, either indefinitely or hyperbolically, for any moderately large number.

Example sentences -

> **1.** More than *three* **dozen** *of* President Obama's top fundraisers snagged VIP invites.
>
> **2.** The owner receives 15 cents from the egg company for every *one* **dozen** *of* eggs produced.
>
> **3.** He's written the music for *half a* **dozen** *of* actor and director Kenneth Branagh's films.

As the notes mentions the *of* after **dozen** is often dropped. And hence it's more common to use **dozen** like an adjective/determiner, with no *of* between **dozen** and the noun. You will see people hardly retain *of*, and some indeed object to the use of *of* there. Collins Cobuild Dictionary is one of them.  
Many dictionaries categories **dozen** as adjective or determiner.

> **4.** The author or co-author of *two* **dozen** books, Connery also taught more than four decades at universities including Stanford and Duke.

So what happens with sentences #1,#2 and #3. Are they incorrect?

No, the use of *of* there is fine. They are examples of partitive construction - some from a large group of things.

When **dozens** is used, it doesn't mean **twelve**, it means **a large group of things**. There is often an *of* between **dozens** and a noun.

> **5.** But, first in Kuwait City, **dozens** *of* children and women are burned alive after a fire ripped through a packed wedding tent.
>
> **6.** We collected **dozens and dozens** *of* shells on the beach.
>
> **7.** The ​refugees ​arrived **by the dozen/in ​their dozens**.

**Usage Note From MW Usage Dictionary -**

> **Dozen** has two plurals, a zero form *dozen* (just like the singular) and an inflected *dozens*. When a number is put before the
>   noun, the zero form plural is used:
>
> > He that kills me some six or seven dozen of Scots - Shakespeare, *I Henry IV*, 1598
> >
> > ... stript away ten dozen Yards of Fringe —Jonathan Swift, *A Tale of a Tub*, 1710
> >
> > ... several million dozen pairs —B. Eldred Ellis, *Gloves and the Glove Trade*, 1921
> >
> > ... consuming... twelve dozen oysters, eight quarts of orange juice — Frank Sullivan, *The Night the Old Nostalgia Burned Down*, 1953
>
> When the number is not specified, *dozens* is used:
>
> > ... worked in dozens of minor roles in television plays — *Current Biography*, June 1965
> >
> > Evans 1957 notes that *of* used to be common after *dozen*:
> >
> > I bought you a dozen of shirts — Shakespeare, *I Henry IV*, 1598
> >
> > ... a dozen or so of people were sitting about — Archibald Marshall, *Anthony Dare*, 1923
>
> This construction is now felt to be old-fashioned and is no longer
>   used much. We do, of course, retain *of* after *dozens*:
>
> > Dozens of times since . . . I have been asked . . . — Joseph Wood Krutch, *American Scholar*, Spring 1955

---

It's correct to write the following -

> He has bought four dozen mangoes.
>
> Four dozen (of) mangoes were delivered from the storehouse.
>
> There are dozens of mangoes scattered on the floor.

Comment: Might want better examples for 1 & 2. The 'of' there denotes possesion, it has nothing to do with dozen. "I have one pen." vs "It is one *of* his pens"

Comment: @Shane I didn't understand you fully. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: In your examples 1 & 2 the word *of* is there to indicate that the thing in question belongs to someone. It has nothing to do with the word dozen. It it denoting that something is part of a whole. "The fundraisers *of* Obama". "Some *of* his films." "The sleeve *of* his coat" I don't know what more to say than that. The examples don't show what you want them to show.

Comment: @Shane You got it. Exactly that's what I mean by *partitive construction*. :-)

Comment: That's very confusing. You have them listed as examples that demonstrate the OED rule, and then halfway through your answer you mention that they aren't in fact examples of OED's rule and that you were using them to demonstrate something completely different.

Comment: @Shane Oh now I get your point. Yes I tried to demonstrate. OED doesn't say in which circumstances it has to be *of* construction and when it will be without *of* construction. Before I saw MW usage guide I tried to find example sentences with *of* construction and they are very few in numbers, and all those example sentences the construction is partitive. Colins Cobuild objected to the use of *of* there. So I came to the conclusion that *of* is fine only in cases when we have to use partitive construction. But later MW usage guide cleared all sort of confusion stating *of* construction (cont)

Comment: (cont...) is also possible but those are actually old-fashioned.