# Fourteen dozen costs / fourteen dozens cost / fourteen dozen cost

Tags: singular-vs-plural, exam-questions

At present rate of exchange, _______  2$

Which among the three options is correct to fill in the above blank ?

> 1. fourteen dozen costs.
> 2. fourteen dozens cost.
> 3. fourteen dozen cost.

I guess we use singular nouns after cardinal numbers so *fourteen dozen*  should be the correct choice but then will verb agree with *fourteen* or with *dozen* i.e. will it be plural (cost) or singular (costs)?

Comment: What do you mean we use singular nouns after cardinals? You have three option**s** in your question.

Comment: @Cardinal I mean to say fourteen dozen XYZ is correct not fourteen dozens XYZ  but ' fourteen dozens of ' XYZ is correct. Am I correct ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct your mistake.

Comment: You may want to see this post: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71408/four-dozen-or-four-dozens/71417#71417

Comment: You can rule out #2, for a start. Nobody would pluralise ***dozens*** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Not *anymore*, I think you mean. Pluralizing dozens, hundreds, and other number groups is extremely archaic.

Comment: This question is related to the "Four dozen" question, but it is not a duplicate.  The _dozen/dozens_ choice is addressed in those answers, but i don't see where the _cost/costs_ choice is.

Comment: @Adam I see your point and I didn't flag this question as a duplicate.      
 @ user: Would you tell me more about the context and that "fourteen dozen" describes what? I expect either to see a noun after "fourteen dozen" or to understand a noun from the context.

Answer (score -1):

According to Oxford Dictionary,

3 dozens [plural] ( informal) a lot of people or things.
They arrived in dozens (= in large numbers) .

That means "dozen " can be " plural ". On that note, we can say only your sentence number two [ fourteen dozens cost ] is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you are wrong. #2 is wrong.

Comment: @Cardinal explain please